# When methods could be applied to more than one object

Tags: object-oriented-design

I was reading on this slide show presentation about [Elder Scrolls 6](http://whatculture.com/gaming/elder-scrolls-6-10-things-fans-want-to-see?page=9). The author writes:

> Add some different directions to swing your weapons, more tactical
>   options, feinting, parrying, literally anything

Let's define a few words here:

[feinting](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feinting): a quick movement that you make to trick an opponent

[Parrying](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parry): to defend yourself by turning or pushing aside (a punch, a weapon, etc.)

In a game the above actions can be taken by the player or an opponent.

1. Given these actions can be taken **without** a weapon, they're actions a character (the player, enemy, or npc) can make, does it make sense to have the methods `feint()` and `parry()` in the `Character` class?

Swing can be done in two ways, I can swing my sword or I can swing and punch. Suppose the game allows hand to hand combat and weapons such as swords,

2. Would it make sense to have `swing()` in the character class?

This way the method can check if a weapon is equipped `(isEquipped)` and if the weapon can be swung (a characteristic of swords and battleaxes) or I can `swing()` with my empty hand regardless of what weapon my other hand is holding.

Comment: You could set this up as a character ability, especially if different races or classes had different ways to do it. You could just as easily make it a weapon ability, and have a default "fist" weapon. Making it a weapon ability also makes sense if there are weapons that disable the ability to parry (like a large maul or something).

Comment: Mapping character capabilities to methods on a class has always seemed a bit inflexible to me.  What if you want to add a capability to an existing character, or create a new character with different capabilities?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I agree, but how would you solve that problem?

Comment: @Deacon - I guess maybe it's context specific, to me it makes sense to place it in `Character` but as you pointed out, it can fit in `Weapon`. I guess I'd have think more harder about the capabilities of the characters, and available weapons.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Are you talking about a feature in ES6 that allows you to tweak your characters? Or are you wondering how you would model a game if you were to write it in an object oriented way?

Comment: @MartinMaat - How I would model it if I were to write in an OO way. I just included the ES6 reference because that's what made me ask the question. I was reading that article and I was wondering if the `swing()` feature were added where would it go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only place for these functions are in the `Character` class. The weapons do not actually perform these actions. They are tools used while the character performs them.

From a coding perspective these functions need to appear in the `Character` class because you may want to alter how the weapon reacts (ie maybe the character is poisoned or hurt and this affects the chance of a successful parry).

The `Weapon` class provides a good way to get some basic information about the weapon the character is holding and its capabilities, but in and of itself is only a small part of the bigger picture.

In general it is a good idea to start from a point of building classes around how the real world works (of course you may need to diverge from it, but its a good starting point). In the real world people parry/attack/swing. Weapons cannot do any of that.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking! If I had a Sword, I can also extend my arms with that sword in hand, in the real world you could say I stabbed the enemy but you can extend your hands with or without a weapon. It's the `Character` that has the `extend()` method and it will decided what to do. if the `Character` has a `Sword` or `Knife` and contact has been made then proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I do not expect the game to be modeled either way. A character may be a class alright but the character as such probably does not have methods like SwingWeapon, nor would the weapon itself, because the character and the weapon are not objects in the sense you may expect when you see them in the game.

They would have no behavior whatsoever, they are just 3D models. The game creates an illusion of a little man or woman that you would perceive as an entity. It is the point of the game to make you believe that, to make it a credible "object". If you are a programmer, you may see an object and think there must be a class encapsulating all that what looks like behavior.

But I would expect the graphics models to only contain the geometry. Then you would have a player object independent from any character. A script responds to the player's command. If that command is "Attack", a sequence is played specific for a series of models that are active at that time (selected by the player at the start of the game), like character A plus weapon B. They would be animated in sync without one knowing about the other, by an animator object that does not know or care if it is animating an attack, a drop dead sequence or a running movement. Animations would be pre-recorded sequences of positions of points (possibly the result of motion capture exercises). Depending on the character and the weapon the character is holding, a different animation of reference points would be played. An animation would be just data. The animations to be played are determined by a table of currently visible models linked to a particular command.

When a player drops a weapon it is just flagged to no longer be part of the animations to be performed together.

I am not a 3D games developer though, this is what I make of looking at games and what I know about 3D programming in general.

Comment: What you wrote is true, but game still has to keep track of health points, player inventory etc.